# How do I bind functions to all input elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, each

let's say I have this set of HTML-markup and CSS

```
#CSS

.inputhelp_text { background: #000; color: #fff; }
.nodisplay { display: none; }

<input class="inputhelp" id="firstname" /><span class="inputhelp_text nodisplay" id="help_firstname">Write in your firstname</span>

<input class="inputhelp" id="lastname" /><span class="inputhelp_text nodisplay" id="help_lastname">Write in your lastname</span>
```

Using jQuery, I need to bind a function to all input fields (I guess using jQuery's EACH function) so that when I click the input field, it should switch the class of each span to only "inputhelp_text". I've gotten this to work in two separate functions for each field, but since I have alot of fields, I know there's a better way to solve it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: rtfm: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: I'm not used to jQuery, so even with a manual things start out slow. "Thank" you.

Comment: that why reading the documentation might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the each function:

```
$("input").each(function() {
  // this points to the input DOM element
  // $(this) is the jQuery wrapped element
});
```

For example you could have:

```
$(this).removeClass("inputhelp");
$(this).addClass("inputhelp_text");
```

inside the callback.

Comment: Could this work as well?? To select all inputs with class "inputhelp" ?

$('input[class=inputhelp]').bind('focus',function() { // do something }

Comment: Yes, but $("input.inputhelp") or $(".inputhelp") are more simple selectors that do the same thing.

Comment: Please remember that shorter (more non-spesific) triggers makes the search for it inside the DOM slower. Much like xpath queries; specifying a longer more spesific path speeds up the query.

Answer (score 2):

You want to bind handlers to the `blur()` and `focus()` events:

```
$(".inputhelp").focus(function() {
  $("span.inputhelp_text:visible").addClass("nodisplay");
  $(this).next("span.inputhelp_text").removeClass("nodisplay");
}).blur(function() {
  $("span.inputhelp_text").addClass("nodisplay");
});
```

Normally I'd recommend using jQuery effects like `hide()` and `show()` but these only really work with block level elements. `<span>` are inline so this won't work.

Comment: @bakkelun details would undoubtedly be useful

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this situation is the following. Let us say that you have a set of `$("input")`'s that you want to bind to in some way, for example you want to add a class of `.invalid` when they are empty:

```
$("input").each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.focus(function (e) {
        $this.removeClass("invalid");
      });

      $this.blur(function (e) {
        if ($this.val() == "") {
          $this.addClass("invalid");
        }
      });
    });
```

By storing a reference to `$(this)` returned from `$.fn.each`, you can now bind to events on each of the elements individually.